# Multiple instances of class with static constructor

Tags: java

I have existing design of sort of "singleton" implementation with static constructor.
I want to be able to destroy and recreate new instance.

Can this be done without changing the base design?

This is simplified prototype:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ClassA.doWork();
     ClassA.destruct();

     ClassA.doWork(); // <--I need new instance here
}

public class ClassA {
    private static ClassA inst = new ClassA();
    protected ClassA() {
        //init      
    }   
    public static void doWork(){
        //do work
    }   
    public static void destruct(){
        inst = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might do the inst = new ClassA() in your doWork() method if you need a new instance EVERYTIME you call that method.

Comment: *Can this be done without changing the base design?* Probably. *Should I keep the base design?* Probably not.

Comment: not every time, only when the instance is explicitly destroyed

Comment: @assylias, I agree but this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

If you're determined to go down this route, and don't like the null checks on every method, you could change your "destruct" approach to "reset":

```
    public static void reset(){
        inst = new ClassA();
    }
```

Call that instead of destruct.

But, seriously, don't do it... spend time now to refactor this mess or it'll come back to bite you!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to `doWork` Method:

```
public static void doWork()
{
    if(inst == null)
    {
        inst = new ClassA();
    }
    //do work
}
```

OR

Add a separate method to create instance, (similar to how you have to destory)

```
public static ClassA init()
{
    if(inst == null)
    {
        inst = new ClassA();
    }
    return inst;
}
```

Comment: the problem with that, that I have more then one doWork() methods, i will have to add this section to every one of them.

Comment: then use the separate method `init` to create instance.

Answer (score 0):

The method `doWork` should check against `null` instances and either throw an `IllegalStateException` or create a new instance of `ClassA` and then do the logic:

```
        public static void doWork(){
            if (inst == null){
                // throw new IllegalStateException("instance has been destroyed");
                // or
                inst = new ClassA();
            }
            // doWork now
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance in the `doWork` method like:

```
  private static ClassA inst;
    public static void doWork() {
        if (inst == null) {
            inst = new ClassA();
        }
    }
```